# model_main.py fails to traing mobilenet ssd v2 - tensorflow object detection api

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using TensorFlow 1.15 and trying to fine-tune mobilenetSSDv2 using TensorFlow object detection API with my own dataset.

I created my tf records the way stated in the tf repo [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/using_your_own_dataset.md) and read the images like this

```
with tf.gfile.GFile(folder_path+"temp.jpeg", 'rb') as fid:
    encoded_image_data = fid.read()
```

I have divided my points by the width and height like needed, then I tweaked the config to fit my number of classes but when I run the train process I still get this error (I unsuccessfully tried a lot of things to make it work)

```
    ...
    
    ...
    
    tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node Dataset_map_transform_and_pad_input_data_fn_423}} assertion failed: [[0.576413691][0.335303724][0.766369045]...] [[0.155026451][0.439418][0.299206346]...]     [[{{node Assert/AssertGuard/Assert}}]]      [[IteratorGetNext]]
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./object_detection/model_main.py", line 108, in <module>
        tf.app.run()   File "/home/mai/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/platform/app.py", line 40, in run
        _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)   File "/home/mai/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 299, in run
        _run_main(main, args)   File "/home/mai/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 250, in _run_main
        sys.exit(main(argv))   File "./object_detection/model_main.py", line 104, in main
        tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_specs[0])   File "/home/mai/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py", line 473, in train_and_evaluate
        return executor.run()   File "/home/mai/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py", line 613, in run
        return self.run_local()   File "/home/mai/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py", line 714, in run_local
        saving_listeners=saving_listeners)   File "/home/mai/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 370, in train
        loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)   File "/home/mai/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1161, in _train_model
        return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)   File "/home/mai/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1195, in _train_model_default
        saving_listeners)   File "/home/mai/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1494, in _train_with_estimator_spec
        _, loss = mon_sess.run([estimator_spec.train_op, estimator_spec.loss])   File "/home/mai/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 754, in run
        run_metadata=run_metadata)   File "/home/mai/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1259, in run
        run_metadata=run_metadata)   File "/home/mai/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1360, in run
        raise six.reraise(*original_exc_info)   File "/home/mai/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 703, in reraise
        raise value   File "/home/mai/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1345, in run
        return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/mai/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1418, in run
        run_metadata=run_metadata)   File "/home/mai/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1176, in run
        return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/mai/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 956, in run
        run_metadata_ptr)   File "/home/mai/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1180, in _run
        feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)   File "/home/mai/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1359, in _do_run
        run_metadata)   File "/home/mai/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1384, in _do_call
        raise type(e)(node_def, op, message) 
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  assertion failed: [[0.576413691][0.335303724][0.766369045]...] [[0.155026451][0.439418][0.299206346]...]      [[{{node Assert/AssertGuard/Assert}}]]      [[IteratorGetNext]]
```

My config file and pbtxt

```
# SSD with Mobilenet v2 configuration for MSCOCO Dataset.
# Users should configure the fine_tune_checkpoint field in the train config as
# well as the label_map_path and input_path fields in the train_input_reader and
# eval_input_reader. Search for "PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED" to find the fields that
# should be configured.

model {
  ssd {
    num_classes: 5
    box_coder {
      faster_rcnn_box_coder {
        y_scale: 10.0
        x_scale: 10.0
        height_scale: 5.0
        width_scale: 5.0
      }
    }
    matcher {
      argmax_matcher {
        matched_threshold: 0.5
        unmatched_threshold: 0.5
        ignore_thresholds: false
        negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
        force_match_for_each_row: true
      }
    }
    similarity_calculator {
      iou_similarity {
      }
    }
    anchor_generator {
      ssd_anchor_generator {
        num_layers: 6
        min_scale: 0.2
        max_scale: 0.95
        aspect_ratios: 1.0
        aspect_ratios: 2.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.5
        aspect_ratios: 3.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.3333
      }
    }
    image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        height: 300
        width: 300
      }
    }
    box_predictor {
      convolutional_box_predictor {
        min_depth: 0
        max_depth: 0
        num_layers_before_predictor: 0
        use_dropout: false
        dropout_keep_probability: 0.8
        kernel_size: 1
        box_code_size: 4
        apply_sigmoid_to_scores: false
        conv_hyperparams {
          activation: RELU_6,
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.00004
            }
          }
          initializer {
            truncated_normal_initializer {
              stddev: 0.03
              mean: 0.0
            }
          }
          batch_norm {
            train: true,
            scale: true,
            center: true,
            decay: 0.9997,
            epsilon: 0.001,
          }
        }
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: 'ssd_mobilenet_v2'
      min_depth: 16
      depth_multiplier: 1.0
      conv_hyperparams {
        activation: RELU_6,
        regularizer {
          l2_regularizer {
            weight: 0.00004
          }
        }
        initializer {
          truncated_normal_initializer {
            stddev: 0.03
            mean: 0.0
          }
        }
        batch_norm {
          train: true,
          scale: true,
          center: true,
          decay: 0.9997,
          epsilon: 0.001,
        }
      }
    }
    loss {
      classification_loss {
        weighted_sigmoid {
        }
      }
      localization_loss {
        weighted_smooth_l1 {
        }
      }
      hard_example_miner {
        num_hard_examples: 3000
        iou_threshold: 0.99
        loss_type: CLASSIFICATION
        max_negatives_per_positive: 3
        min_negatives_per_image: 3
      }
      classification_weight: 1.0
      localization_weight: 1.0
    }
    normalize_loss_by_num_matches: true
    post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 1e-8
        iou_threshold: 0.6
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 100
      }
      score_converter: SIGMOID
    }
  }
}

train_config: {
  batch_size: 32
  optimizer {
    rms_prop_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        exponential_decay_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.004
          decay_steps: 800720
          decay_factor: 0.95
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
      decay: 0.9
      epsilon: 1.0
    }
  }
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "/home/mai/Downloads/ssdlite_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_05_09/checkpoints/model.ckpt"
  from_detection_checkpoint: true # added 
  fine_tune_checkpoint_type:  "detection"
  # Note: The below line limits the training process to 200K steps, which we
  # empirically found to be sufficient enough to train the pets dataset. This
  # effectively bypasses the learning rate schedule (the learning rate will
  # never decay). Remove the below line to train indefinitely.
  num_steps: 10000
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    ssd_random_crop {
    }
  }
}

train_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input: "pathto/train_608.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "pathto/vehicle_label_map.pbtxt"
}

eval_config: {
  num_examples: 100
  # Note: The below line limits the evaluation process to 10 evaluations.
  # Remove the below line to evaluate indefinitely.
  max_evals: 10
  metrics_set : "coco_detection_metrics"
}

eval_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "pathto/frames/eval_608.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "pathto/vehicle_label_map.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_readers: 1
}
# and given pbtxt 

item {
  name: "car"
  id: 1
  display_name: "car"
}
item {
  name: "motorbike"
  id: 2
  display_name: "motorbike"
}
item {
  name: "bus"
  id: 3
  display_name: "bus"
}
item {
  name: "truck"
  id: 4
  display_name: "truck"
}
item {
  name: "van"
  id: 5
  display_name: "van"
}
```

**Edit:**
Here's the conversion to tf records code

```py
    def create_tf_example(image_prop_dict):
        height = image_prop_dict['im_height']
        width = image_prop_dict['im_width']
        filename = image_prop_dict['im_name']  # Filename of the image. Empty if image is not from file
        encoded_image_data = image_prop_dict['encoded_image']  # Encoded image bytes
        image_format = bytes('jpeg', 'utf-8')  # b'jpeg' or b'png'
    
        xmins = image_prop_dict['x_mins']  # List of normalized left x coordinates in bounding box (1 per box)
        xmaxs = image_prop_dict['x_maxs']  # List of normalized right x coordinates in bounding box
        # (1 per box)
        ymins = image_prop_dict['x_mins']  # List of normalized top y coordinates in bounding box (1 per box)
        ymaxs = image_prop_dict['y_maxs']  # List of normalized bottom y coordinates in bounding box
        # (1 per box)
        classes_text = image_prop_dict['classes_labels']  # List of string class name of bounding box (1 per box)
        classes = image_prop_dict['classes_ints']  # List of integer class id of bounding box (1 per box)
    
        tf_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
            'image/height': dataset_util.int64_feature(height),
            'image/width': dataset_util.int64_feature(width),
            'image/filename': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
            'image/source_id': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
            'image/encoded': dataset_util.bytes_feature(encoded_image_data),
            'image/format': dataset_util.bytes_feature(image_format),
            'image/object/bbox/xmin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmins),
            'image/object/bbox/xmax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmaxs),
            'image/object/bbox/ymin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymins),
            'image/object/bbox/ymax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymaxs),
            'image/object/class/text': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(classes_text),
            'image/object/class/label': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(classes),
        }))
        return tf_example
    
    
    def convert_jsons_in_folder(folder_path, classes_dict):
        """loops through a folder of json labels and converts every json to the yolo format and saves it to a .txt
        of the same name.
    
        :param folder_path: str path to the folder containing the json files
        :param classes_dict: dict [class name] = class number
        """
        json_name_list = []
        image_dictionaries = []
        for file_name in os.listdir(folder_path):
            if file_name.endswith(".json"):
                json_name_list.append(file_name)
    
        for json_file_name in tqdm(json_name_list):
            # read json file
            # get list of boxes and labels
            # fill dictionary ,save it to dictionary 
            json_path = os.path.join(folder_path, json_file_name)
            
            with tf.gfile.GFile(folder_path+"temp.jpeg", 'rb') as fid:
                encoded_image_data = fid.read()
    
            with open(json_path) as json_file_r:
                json_data = json.load(json_file_r)
                im_width = json_data["imageWidth"]
                im_height = json_data["imageHeight"]
                image_dictionary = {'im_height': im_height,
                                    'im_width': im_width,
                                    'im_name': bytes(json_file_name.replace(".json", ".jpg"), 'utf-8'),
                                    'encoded_image': encoded_image_data,  # image.tostring(),
                                    'x_mins': [],
                                    'x_maxs': [],
                                    'y_mins': [],
                                    'y_maxs': [],
                                    'classes_labels': [],
                                    'classes_ints': []}
    
                for labelme_detection in json_data["shapes"]:
    
                    points = labelme_detection["points"]
                    if len(points) > 0:
                        class_label = labelme_detection["label"]
                        # calculate relative points using original width and height (boxes were on the original image)
                        image_dictionary['x_mins'].append(min(points[0][0], points[1][0]) / im_width)
                        image_dictionary['x_maxs'].append(max(points[0][0], points[1][0]) / im_width)
                        image_dictionary['y_mins'].append(min(points[0][1], points[1][1]) / im_height)
                        image_dictionary['y_maxs'].append(max(points[0][1], points[1][1]) / im_height)
                        bytes_label = bytes(class_label, 'utf-8')
                        image_dictionary['classes_labels'].append(bytes_label)
                        image_dictionary['classes_ints'].append(classes_dict[class_label] + 1)
                
                image_dictionaries.append(image_dictionary)
               
        return image_dictionaries


# ..
# ..
# main  
examples = convert_list_of_folders(args.source, classes_dict)
# ..
# ..
# ..

    for i in range(len(examples)):
        # for example in examples:
        tf_example = create_tf_example(examples[i])
        eval_writer.write(tf_example.SerializeToString())
```

Comment: Looks like you have a problem in the dataset. Can you post the code you use t ogenerate the TFRecords? (The rest looks OK)

Comment: edited it to include the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was indeed the data, to fix the error I used this [repo](https://github.com/mwindowshz/YoloToTfRecords) to convert my data to the tf record

the data needs to be converted to the YOLO format for this but that was pretty straight forward